# drawing arrow dynamically on windows form

Tags: c#, winforms

i want to draw an arrow of different type with following requirement
 Arrow location, which is an enum with the following properties
        Left, Right, Both, None. 
Arrow types: The type of the arrow should be as attached
  for this  Use enum
Arrow Size
        Again enum with Small, medium and Big
please give me some idea how to do this.

Comment: Read the stack overflow FAQ.  Tell us what you have tried.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do you want to change the mouse cursor, while the mouse being over a specific control?
You may read about the System.Windows.Forms.Cursor:

```
Cursor.Current = Cursors.Arrow;
```

You can also set an own defined cursor and the size can be changed. If you really want to draw an arrow for instance on a control, you may register the paint event on the control

```
private void control_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
}
```

Then you can use the graphics instance to draw all kind of things.

Comment: The shotgun approach to answering a question is never a good one.  You need to lock the OP down - get them to express *exactly* what they are after - and make them show their attempts.